# Is it possible to filter out some database rows in the middleware?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

*Sorry for the length of this question, I could not make it shorter and still meaningful.*

We have a very simple application with two simple models `Company` and `Building`, with a many-to-many relationship between them. Each has a `restricted` attribute. `User` is a regular Django `User` class, except we add a `show` attribute.

```py
# models.py

class User(AbstractUser):
    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    restricted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    restricted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company, related_name='buildings')
```

The views are regular Django REST Framework view sets, and the serializers are as simple as possible:

```py
# views.py

class CompanyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer


class BuildingViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Building.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BuildingSerializer


# serializers.py

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'


class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Now we want to implement this behavior**: if `user.show` is `False`, the user must **not** be able to see (in the views) the `restricted` `Company` and `Building`.

In other words, if `john` is an `User` and `john.show is False`, `john` can see (in the views) `normal_company` and `normal_building`, but **not** `restricted_company` or `restricted_building`.

To achieve this, **we don't want to edit the views / the serializers** if that's possible, because there are a lot of them (this a simplified version of a real project which is much bigger).

My team thought about using the middleware. We tried to dynamically change `Company.objects` and `Building.objects`:

```py
# middleware.py

class FilterMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        user = get_user()  # Get the user somehow.

        if not user.show:
            # Replace objects.
            for model in (Company, Building):
                model.objects = model.objects.filter(restricted=False)

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

But this, for some unknown reason, does not work: `john` can still see the restricted companies. We then tried to dynamically update the `django.db.models.Manager.get_queryset` method:

```py
# middleware.py
class FilterMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        user = get_user()

        if not user.show:
            models.Manager.get_queryset = get_restricted_queryset

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response


def get_restricted_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Conditions for the filter later.
    hiding_conditions = {
        "Company": Q(restricted=True),
        "Building": Q(companies__restricted=True) | Q(restricted=True),
    }

    model_name = self.model.__name__

    if model_name in hiding_conditions:
        # We must filter the model out, so apply the hiding conditions.
        hiding_condition = hiding_conditions[model_name]

        return self._queryset_class(
            model=self.model, using=self._db, hints=self._hints
        ).exclude(hiding_condition)
    else:
        return self._queryset_class(model=self.model, using=self._db, hints=self._hints)
```

But this does not work — and that's weird: when I fetch the companies, it is actually *only* the `User` model which is called by `get_queryset`, so `get_restricted_queryset` has no effect.

Now, we are really stuck. Does anyone have an idea which could help us? Or is it just that the middleware is not supposed to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need middleware (as middleware only deals in request and responses, which are an abstraction level below QuerySets). You can do this in DRF using a custom FilterBackend, as such:
**Update: Filter nested companies too!**

```
from rest_framework import filters

class IsRestrictedFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if request.user and user.is_authenticated and not user.show:
            if queryset.model and queryset.model in [Company, Building]:
                queryset = queryset.filter(restricted=False)
                if queryset.model == Building:
                    return queryset.filter(companies__restricted=False)
        return queryset
```

then you add this filter backend to your settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['yourapp.filter_backends.IsRestrictedFilterBackend']
}
```

...or you can use it on a ViewSet basis:

```
class BuildingViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Building.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BuildingSerializer
    filter_backends = [yourapp.filter_backends.IsRestrictedFilterBackend]
```

Comment: I'd normally not do this but since you're a new user, if my answer or any other works and solves your issue, consider marking it as the correct answer by pressing the ticket below the voting buttons

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
It does work, do you know however a way to make it work also for nested fields returned by the serializers (without touching the serializers)?
For instance, if I fetch some building which is linked to a restricted company, it will always return this restricted company.